# Adding spaces in About Me of Profile

Tags: support, profile-page

When editing my **About Me** of my profile I notice that it ignores spacing (keeping multiple blank spaces to make it look like identation) and just keeps one blank space instead. Same thing when typing in the edit window. Is there any way around this?

Comment: This applies to *all* markdown text fields (e.g. questions, answers, tag wikis, etc.), not just your About Me section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [HTML named entities](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/named-character-references.html) (`&nbsp;` for spaces) in the About Me section of your profile.